# cannot read properties of undefined (reading'errors')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Eci.png)

I'm new to full-stack development.
I'm running my application on localhost, node.js for backend, react js for front-end, and MongoDB
everything is connected to the localhost when I try to login from the admin dashboard this error is shown any help

Answer (score 0):

the error.networkError.result value is undefined, so there is no there is no undefined.errors try console.log(error.networkError) and go through the keys maybe also console.log(Object.keys(error.networkError))